# Visual Studio Community 2017, ASP.Net and NET Core - No Core Project Templates Available

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I've just installed Visual Studio 2017 as well as the NET Core 2.0 SDK.

When I come to create a new ASP.Net Core Web project, the only option I have available to me is the "ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)" however various tutorials and Microsoft guides refer to other project templates available with this exact setup.

In fact, no "NET Core" project templates are present within the New Project form.

Any clues please?

Comment: probably you didn't install VS required modules

Comment: @Alexan The requirements were "Visual Studio 2017" and "NET Core 2.0.0 SDK" - nothing else. Not seen any mention of any other installable modules

Comment: please see picture below

Comment: try restarting your computer

Comment: Already tried. I'm going to try uninstalling NET Core and VS2017...

Answer (score 1):

Did you install: .NET Core Cross-platform development module?

[image]

Comment: Yep, I ensured that this option was selected during installation

Comment: and ASP.NET and web development?

Comment: Correct - all web-related options were selected